# How can I preserve a user created during installation between major upgrades?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am using the WiX util `User` element to create a user during installation. We are using a block similar to the following

```
<util:User Id="serviceUser"
               Name="[USER_NAME]"
               CanNotChangePassword="yes"
               CreateUser="yes"
               FailIfExists="yes"
               LogonAsService="yes"
               RemoveOnUninstall="yes"
               Password="[USER_PASS]">
</util:User>
```

I want to make sure that the user will always be created and I want it to be rolled back during uninstall but not during upgrade because that would mess up some credentials that we use.

I opened the generated MSI in Orca to see the generated action sequence and was confused

[image]

All the custom actions for managing users appear in the custom action table, but the `CreateUser` `CreateUserRollback` and `RemoveUser` actions have very strange `type` values.

Referring to the `InstallExecuteSequence` table, the only action that is actually sequenced is `ConfigureUsers`.
[image]

How are `CreateUser` and `CreateUserRollback` sequenced and if I want to control them in a `<InstallExecuteSequence>` block, what sequence order should I give them.

Otherwise, is there a better way that I could accomplish this which I am missing?

Comment: User will be present in User table in ORCA. Also the custom action with create user is 'ConfigureUsers' and it is executed before 'InstallFiles'